# Image displayed differently in different screen

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-position

I have a fixed image placed using this code:

```
<a href="http://website.com" onMouseOver='img_mo5.src="style/images/download-btn-hover.png"' onMouseOut='img_mo5.src="style/images/download-btn.png"'><img style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 865px; height: 58%;z-index: 0;" src="style/images/download-btn.png" name="img_mo5" alt="" width="450px" height="300px"></a>
```

The problem is that in bigger screens the image is placed in the middle of the screen instead of in the left bottom corner (it works fine in 15" screen)

How do I fix this using `inline-css style= (attribute)` code in HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you say no CSS but you have inline CSS in your code.

Second, why are you using position: fixed with right: 865px?

The reason the image appears in the middle on larger screens is that you're specifying a direct pixel value. You'll want to either change

```
right: 865px;
```

to

```
left: 0;
```

Or change the link to float left instead, such as:

```
float: left;
```

Either way, why are you putting CSS inline? It is not the recommended or correct usage of CSS. CSS is designed to separate content from styling, so putting it inline defeats the purpose.

Comment: Putting inline css on fixed images is very common. Otherwise can the fixed image behave unclear. It's very easy as well using this for img attribute on single images.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it on the left corner of the screen you should be using `left:0` instead of `right:865px`

```
<a href="http://website.com" onMouseOver='img_mo5.src="style/images/download-btn-hover.png"' onMouseOut='img_mo5.src="style/images/download-btn.png"'><img style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; height: 58%;z-index: 0;" src="style/images/download-btn.png" name="img_mo5" alt="" width="450px" height="300px"></a>
```

If you provide a jsfiddle I can help you more.

**Edit:**

About mobile sites like you asked me, most mobile browser doesn't support it pretty well so we use JavaScript to do the job, here is a bunch of examples and much more info http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/

Comment: It works well on bigger screens also now. But not on mobile devices.

Comment: @Felix you didn't asked for mobile sites before, here is some info about using position fixed on mobile sites http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/